# What can I change in my recursive function to make it work correctly?

Tags: javascript

```
function loo(x) {
    if (x >= 10) {
    return;
    loo(x+1)
   }
}
loo(1);
```

A function that calls itself is called a recursive function. In some ways, recursion is analogous to a loop. Both execute the same code multiple times, and both require a condition (to avoid an infinite loop, or rather, infinite recursion in this case). For example, the following loop:

Comment: It's unclear what your question is.  Your question body reads as a statement, rather than saying what you want to happen, and what difficulty you are having achieving that result. "to make it work correctly" doesn't tell us anything

Comment: But the first pointer is that you can't have a return before a second statement.  It makes the statements after the return **dead code**.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing. If you run this code, it actually does work correctly. It just doesn't output anything. If you want to see some output from it, try running it like this:

```js
function loo(x) 
{
    if (x >= 10) 
    {
        console.log("finished")
        return;
    }
    console.log("x=" + x);
    loo(x+1);
}
loo(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let trace your code :

    function loo(x) {
        if (x >= 10) {
        return;
        loo(x+1)
       }
    }
    loo(1);

the function never works because if block always return noting so change the some statement of  code like this :

    function loo(x) {
        if (x >= 10) {
        return;
            }
        loo(x+1);
        }
then call :

    loo(1);
```